# Laravel lots of events

Tags: php, laravel

I'm building a ticketSystem api in Laravel. And I've got a lot of events. And I'm wondering if I'm doing it right. So for example when a user is created it fires the event: **CreateUserEvent**

That event has a couple of listeners like:

- **CreateUser**
- **CreatePackage**
- **SendEmail**

I've got for almost every crud things an event with multiple listeners. Is this the normal way of doing this kind of things? In my controllers I almost fire only events.

I've already watched a couple of videos about events for example (https://laracasts.com/series/intermediate-laravel/episodes/3) But I'm still a bit confused.

So basically my question is: Is it normal that your webapp exist out of a lot of events? If it's not where do you use events?

Comment: If you want to do X every time Y happens then triggering an event when Y happens and having an X_listener listening in order to do X is a good way to go. I'm a bit confused as to why `CreateUser` would be a listener to a `CreateUserEvent`

Comment: This question isn’t really suitable for Stack Overflow as it’s primarily opinion-based.

Comment: @MartinBean I do not agree with you. This is a good question, not primarily opinion based as he asks for the right way to use events. Not asking how you (and by you I mean anyone who reads the question) use events.

Comment: @Ben “So basically my question is: Is it normal that your webapp exist out of a lot of events?” This is not a programming issue. This is asking for opinions of other developers on how they structure their apps.

Comment: If there is a good practise for it people can ask for it. Its a matter of perspective where you decide to stay in the corner you're standing. Lately I've seen SO become a bit preachy about what you are allowed to ask and what not. It wouldn't hurt the community to be nicer and help people with these subjects as well. There's an unclear thing from the askers perspective and he's reaching out for help/guidance.

Comment: @Ben I totally agree with that. Stackoverflow is for helping people, and if it's a good question he/she deserves an answer. (That's just my opinion)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, you are making it complex. Use the single event listener for a single event and do the actions in that event handler. For example:

### Pseudo code

```
// In EventServiceProvider
protected $listen = [
    'user.created' => ['App\Handlers\Events\UserEvents@userCreated'],
],
```

Somewhere in your app:

```
// ...
if($user = User::create($request->all())) {
    app('event')->fire('user.created', $user);
}

...
```

The handler `App\Handlers\Events\UserEvents@userCreated`:

```
<?php namespace App\Handlers\Events;

use App\User;
use App\Package;
use App\Services\Mail\UserMailer;

class UserEvents {

    protected $mailer = null;
    protected $package = null;

    public function __construct(UserMailer $mailer, Package $package)
    {
        $this->mailer = $mailer;
        $this->package = $package;
    }

    public function userCreated(User $user)
    {
        $this->package->create($user); // <-- An action to be taken

        $this->mailer->notifyUser($user); // <-- Another action to be taken
    }

}
```

So, this way, you can handle your events and use the handler to take additional actions for you on a particular event.

Comment: Thanks for the great explanation.